# How to modify the "-h" output.when using optparse.optionParser()

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, optparse

Is there a neat way to modify the "-h" output when usion optparse?
Basically there's a load of additional text I want to add in addition to the "freebie" usage instructions that are ouput.

Or is this completely the wrong approach to doing this?

Answer (score 2):

[optparse.OptionParser](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#optparse.OptionParser) - see description for parameters `usage`, `prog` and `epilog`.

Comment: Thanks for that..... I was trying to use epilog, but was being a complete n00b and my usage was so wrong it wasn't even funny :(